# Random choose of row in table

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms

I have a table loaded from my database in Xamarin.Forms(C#), that have x number of rows. Each row has 3 parameters(type is in() - Id(int), firstword(string), secondword(string). I need to generate a random row from this table/list and get all 3 paramentrs to the new int(id) a strings (string fw, sw). Thanks for your help.

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
{
     conn.CreateTable<Post>();
     var posts = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();
     
     Random r = new Random();
     int i = r.Next(posts.Count);

     int id = ???;
     string fw = ???;
     string sw = ???;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`posts` is a `List`, just get the nth element of the list

```
var post = posts[i];
```